# Database 'mysql' in the server mysql in different OS

Tags: java, mysql

I will explain my situation, my project is an interface in java that can user to log in mysql database, so in this interface, the user must enter the login, password and host(of user in mysql) so the program authenticates by the user root to DB 'mysql' (exist in windows version of mysql) and looking if the user existed in the table user of DB 'mysql'.
my question here is: do this database and the table user exist also in linux version so that i can use my project in different OS.
the second question in this table (user) i found that the password is in code ASCII i want to do test if this password equals to the password ented by the user to authenticate to my project.best regards

Answer (score 0):

The user table exists in all versions of mysql. You would need to create the users in the linux database when you switch to linux. How to create a user is available in this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-user.html

You can compare the password as plain text unless you encrypt it. I think it should work fine.

Comment: First thank You for answering my question. Concerning the second answer , I beg your pardon. i don't understand the compare that You talk about. the password in table user is in code ASCII and the password entering is in String how can i compare between them.best regards

Comment: MySQL encrypts the password when you create the user and decrypts it when you try to login. So if you know the original password given while the user is created, you just need to issue that while logging in. If you want to test it, open your local mysql workbench and connect to your local host. Issue this command in the SQL"create user 'test123'@'localhost' identified by '123456';". Then check the user table "select * from mysql.user". You can see the password is encrypted. Now log in with the new user and the password.